# CSS Media Print @page different properties for each page

Tags: css, media-queries

I create 3 page using css html, and for first and second page i set margin 4cm, but for third page i want set it to 0cm.
This is my css code

```
@media print {
@page
{
    size:8.5in 13in;
    margin:4.5cm 1mm 1mm 1mm; /* this just for page one and two */
    mso-page-orientation: landscape;
}
@page :third {
  margin: 0cm; /* for page 3 but not work*/
}
}
```

How to make different page margin for each page?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no pseudo class like `:third`, you should use [:nth()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#document-page-selectors) page pseudo-class for nth-pages:

```
@page :nth(3) {
  margin: 0cm;
}
```

Comment: This is just working draft of 13 May 2014, so currently there's no other way to handle it.